# Remember-mode-hook not working in emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using GNU Emacs 23.1.1. I used `M-x org-version` to confirm that I have 
Org-mode version 6.34c

When I execute `M-x remember`, the remember buffer opens but I get the message "Symbol's function value is void: nil".  Therefore I think that the `remember-mode-hook` fails because when I enter text in the remember buffer and hit `C-c C-c`, the text doesn't get written to todo.org (specified in the template definition below).

Instead I get the message "Target files for notes must be in Org-mode if not filing to top/bottom". Please help. The relevant entries from my `.emacs` are below:

```
(require 'remember)

(require 'org-remember)

(org-remember-insinuate)

(setq org-directory "~/")

(define-key global-map "\C-cr" 'org-remember)

(setq remember-annotation-functions '(org-remember-annotation))

(setq remember-handler-functions '(org-remember-handler))

(add-hook 'remember-mode-hook 'org-remember-apply-template)

(setq org-remember-templates

'(("Todo" ?t "* TODO %?\n  %i\n  %a" "~/todo.org" "Tasks")))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of fiddling with remember, it's probably better for you to upgrade org-mode. After org-mode v6.36 capturing is done by `org-capture`. Have a look at the info node '9.1 Capture' in the org-manual.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will upgrade org-mode and study org-capture.